# How to Update a column which is created by using cast - identity

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to update column which is created with cast

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
    num INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Token AS 'TK_' + CAST(num VARCHAR(10)),
    name VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('data')
```

If I execute the above query, my result for token column will be  "tk_1".

Is it possible to update/insert manually for that "token" column value?

Comment: The column Token, in your DDL is a Computed Column. You can't UPDATE it, as its value of based off of the value of your column [num]. If you change the value of the column [num], the value of the column Token will change. However, as it's an IDENTITY, then I wouldb't recommend it. Perhaps, what you're looking for is a DEFAULT value?

Comment: A computed column is a virtual column that is not physically stored in the table, unless the column is marked PERSISTED.

Comment: Thank you Larnu..My logic is that for same token id if we receive a new name means my record should be inserted with a same tokenId.

Comment: Yogesh Sharma IF we create with PERSISTED means Is it possible to insert the value to that column

Comment: no you are not covering your requirement properly.Token will not be computed in that case.populate it via code.

Answer (score 1):

Computed columns are read-only and `IDENTITY` values cannot be updated. With the computed column, all you can do is indirectly control the value during inserts using `IDENTITY_INSERT` but that defeats the purpose of using `IDENTITY`.

If you want to update the value after inserted, make it a regular `varchar(13)` column and assign the initial value in an insert trigger. That would allow you to update the value to something else after the initial insert.